# how to get the value of clicked input element of array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

I'd like to send the value of clicked item of array in table to header's input element.

In below case, I always got the first line's value. How do I get the exact clicked line's value?

Here is my code of what I am trying to do:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['wo_arr'])) {
    if(is_array($_SESSION['wo_arr'])) {
        foreach($_SESSION['wo_arr'] as $key => $value)  {
            foreach($value as $k => $v ) {
                $wo_arr[$key][$k] = $v ;
            }
        }
    }
    $num = count($wo_arr['wo_no']);
} else {
    $num = 5 ;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

    function selectWork() {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var data = $(this).find('.wono_arr').val() ;            
            $('#wo_no').val(data);

        });     
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <FORM>

        <p>
            work order # <INPUT size=10 TYPE="text" id=wo_no NAME="wo_no">
        </p>

        <table>

        <?php
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) {
        ?>

            <TR>
                <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" class="wono_arr" NAME="wo_arr[wo_no][]"
                    value="<?php if(isset($wo_arr['wo_no'][$i])) echo $wo_arr['wo_no'][$i]; ?>"
                    onclick="selectWork()">
                </TD>
            </TR>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </TABLE>

    </FORM>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: use, this in the function and by default to the method passed the event, by this object could be found event.current..

Comment: `ng-click="functionName(this)"` `$scope.functionName= function (sender){alert(sender.value)`

Comment: thanks, Álvaro Touzón. i solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `this` on function call :

**HTML**

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" class="wono_arr" NAME="wo_arr[wo_no][]" value="<?php if(isset($wo_arr['wo_no'][$i])) echo $wo_arr['wo_no'][$i]; ?>" onclick="selectWork(this)">
```

And use it in :

**JS**

```
function selectWork(e) {        
   var data = $(e).val();            
   $('#wo_no').val(data);
}
```

Recommended attach click handler to input element instead of using inline javascript like so :

**HTML**

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" class="wono_arr" NAME="wo_arr[wo_no][]" value="<?php if(isset($wo_arr['wo_no'][$i])) echo $wo_arr['wo_no'][$i]; ?>">
```

**JS**

```
$('table').on('click','.wono_arr', function () {
   var data = $(this).val();            
   $('#wo_no').val(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks Norlihazmey Ghazali, your answer is also wonderful. my 5 hours' headache. haha

Answer (score 0):

Define your each element with a common class name and for that class define a click function as follows.

```
//JS
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".wono_arr").click(function(){
        alert("Value"+$(this).val());
        alert($(this).attr('id')+"clicked");
   });
});
</script>
//In your html
<table>
<?php
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="wono_arr" id="<?php echo $wo_arr['wo_no'][$i]; ?>" name="wo_arr[wo_no][]"
                value="<?php if(isset($wo_arr['wo_no'][$i])) echo $wo_arr['wo_no'][$i]; ?>"
            />
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

For multiple HTML element, you can define same class name and then if you define a method using JQuery and If you use that class then the method will work for all the HTML element. When you call the method, get value of current clicked element using **`this`** keyword.